# Find and highlight different words in two string in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two strings

`let old = "if(is_required(ABCD))then is_valid_numeric(ABCD,'3.0')";`

`let new = "if(is_required(PQR))then is_valid_numeric(PQR,'3.0')";`

in above two strings only difference is PQR in new string so want to highlight PQR in yellow.

Also more use cases can occure which are depicted in below image

[image]

I tried below approch in angular pipe.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'highlighter'})
export class Highlighter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, ...args: any[]): number {
    if(!args[0]) return value;
    let text = '';
    value.split('').forEach((val,i)=>{
       if(val != args[0].charAt(i)){
         text +="<span class='highlight'>" + val + "</span>";
       } else {
        text +=val;
       }
    });
    return text;
  }
}
```

html

```
<p [innerHTML]="new | highlighter:old"></p>
```

above approact is using character checking which will not work if strings are of different length.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ahldr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.tsfile=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: In which condition do you want to highlight text ?

Comment: highlight the differences in New string

Comment: https://angular-ivy-spggeq.stackblitz.io/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: stackblitz is not loading .. could you please post link again

Comment: open https://angular-ivy-spggeq.stackblitz.io/ this link and click on `run this project` button

Comment: somewhat near what I want .... 

one thing :  in 2nd example instead of highlighting ID in MR_SEQ_ID .. can we highlight whole word MR_SEQ_ID ?

Comment: we highlight based on difference, so ID is different, so it is good practice to highlight only different part.

Comment: yes ... but as per Business  guys whole word is different :) thats why I asked

Comment: could you please post code here as answer?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda could you please post it as answer ?

Comment: could you please post it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Tip: "before copy and paste, try understand the code"

The pipe works creating an array of word using split(' ') and compare the elements of the array with the "words", so in your example the array becomes

```
['if(isrequired(MEQ_NUM))','then','isvalid'...]
```

So any word is "MEQ_NUM"

You need change your pipe, use some like:

```
export class Highlighter  implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): string {
    if (!args[0])
      return value;
    args.forEach(x=>{
      value=value.split(x).join('<span class="highlight">' + x + '</span>')
    })
    return value
  }
}
```

See that this pipe "split" by the own word, and join with the `<span class=...></span>`

In the before example, the array that create is

```
["if(isrequired(',")', then isvalid"...]
```

The join makes the "trick", [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mnpcqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhight.pipe.ts)

Comment: I want to highlight the difference between two strings. in above code where is the comparison done ?

In pipe argument i am passing old value of string so in args[0] i am getting old value. I have edited the question and included stackblits as well.

Above pipe that you have implemented is just highlighting the words passed as arguments. I need actual differerence between two strings.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ahldr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question :(

Comment: e.g in below two strings `let old = "if(is_required(ABCD))then is_valid_numeric(ABCD,'3.0')";` and `let new = "if(is_required(PQR))then is_valid_numeric(PQR,'3.0')";` only difference is PQR in new string. SO just want to highlight PQR. 

Note : these strings are dynamic